# ¿Cómo enviar mensaje cuando se de click en cualquier elemento del body excepto la tabla?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Hola tengo el siguiente codigo:

```
        <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="box">
                <div class="box-body">
                    <div class="box-header">
                        <h4 class="box-title"><label>Bootstrap Table</label></h4>
                    </div>
                    <table class="table" data-pagination="true" data-click-to-select="true" data-page-list="[5, 10, 15, 20]" data-search="true" class="table-hover" data-field="tableClinical" data-title="Titulo de la tabla" id="table" data-id="table" data-single-select="true">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th data-field="state" data-checkbox="true" id="check" data-align="center"></th>
                                <th data-field="id" data-sortable="true">Item ID</th>
                                <th data-field="name" data-sortable="true">Item Name</th>
                                <th data-field="price" data-sortable="true">Item Price</th>                                   
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Estoy intentando mostrar un alert cuando se de click en cualquier elemento del body que no sea la tabla:

```
$("body").on("click", ":not(.table)", function (e) {
   alert("not table");
});
```

Sin resultados hasta el momento, alguien tiene alguna idea mejor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debes utilizar [event.stopPropagation](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_stoppropagation.asp) para la tabla.

> Así, en el caso de ser "table", el evento no continuará propagándose hacia el `<body>` y lo controlarás de manera independiente.

En [esta página](https://blog.openalfa.com/propagacion-de-eventos-javascript) explican cómo se propagan los eventos desde la parte superior hacia la inferior.

```js
$("body").on("click", function (e) {
   
   alert("not table");
   
});

$("table").on("click", function (e) {
   alert("Te he pillado, no hagas click en la tabla!!");
   e.stopPropagation();   

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="box">
                <div class="box-body">
                    <div class="box-header">
                        <h4 class="box-title"><label>Bootstrap Table</label></h4>
                    </div>
                    <table style="border: 1px solid black;" class="table" data-pagination="true" data-click-to-select="true" data-page-list="[5, 10, 15, 20]" data-search="true" class="table-hover" data-field="tableClinical" data-title="Titulo de la tabla" id="table" data-id="table" data-single-select="true">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th data-field="state" data-checkbox="true" id="check" data-align="center"></th>
                                <th data-field="id" data-sortable="true">Item ID</th>
                                <th data-field="name" data-sortable="true">Item Name</th>
                                <th data-field="price" data-sortable="true">Item Price</th>                                   
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Aquí te he creado una pequeña demostración similar sobre cómo se propagan los eventos hacia "abajo".

```js
$("div").click(function() {
  alert(this.id)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="a" style="background-color: blue; width: 300px; height: 300px" >
<p>A</p>
  <div id="b" style="background-color: yellow; width: 80%; height: 80%">
    <p>B</p>
    <div id="c" style="background-color: red; width: 80%; height: 80%">
    <p>C</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Por último, decirte que ese nivel de profundidad, corresponde con el valor `CSS` [`z-index`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/z-index) que también puedes modificar y/o controlar para operar con él.

Comment: Gracias Alejandro era lo que necesitaba

Comment: Nada, encantado!!

Answer (score 0):

yo te propongo el siguiente camino ya que no me manejo mucho con *JQuery*:

- Obtén en una variable a la etiqueta `body` a través de una clase que le asignes
- Dale una clase a la etiqueta `table`
- Dale un *listener* al evento `click` de la variable que igualamos con la clase que tiene asignada la etiqueta `body`
- Evalúa si el elemento que disparó el evento contiene la clase que le dimos a la etiqueta `body`
- En caso de contener dicha clase simplemente hacemos un `console.log(1)` para comprobar funcionalidad
- En caso contrario podemos hacer un `return` para que no exista una funcionalidad asociada.

```html
     <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
      <title>JS Bin</title>
      <style>
        body {
          background-color: green;
          height: 100vh;
        }
      </style>
    </head>
    <body class="cuerpo">
    <table class="aquiSi">
      <tr>
        <th>Encabezado 1</th>
        <th>Encabezado 2</th>
      </tr>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>Contenido 1</td>
          <td>Contenido 2</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <script>
      let cuerpoHTML = document.querySelector(".cuerpo")
      
      cuerpoHTML.addEventListener("click", (evento) => {
        if (evento.target.className === "cuerpo") {
          console.log(1)
        } 
      })
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```